# error C2280: attempting to reference a deleted function when copying pair<int,int>

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

The following trivial code

```
#include <xutility>

void foo()
{
    std::pair<int, int> a(0, 1);
    const std::pair<int, int> b = a;
}
```

when compiled with Visual C++ compiler Nov 2013 CTP generates an error:
`error C2280: 'std::pair<int,int>::pair(const std::pair<int,int> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function`

Is it a bug in compiler or should I change some compiler flags?

Comment: To begin with, do not include `<xutility>`; it's an internal header. `std::pair` is defined in `<utility>`. Having said that, [can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/VKE63588)

Comment: Thanks, Igor Tandetnik; this code evidently compiles with everything (including VS13 aka vc18 etc.).  However, Microsoft released "updated" Visual Studio compiler named "Nov 13 CTP" http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41151 promising better support for C++11. And this compiler fails here. I will probably submit a bug report.

Comment: "Nov 13 CTP" was released in November 2013, and was the beta version of VS2013. It is quite pointless to file bugs against that. If you want to be on the bleeding edge, there's a [VS 2015 CTP](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-ctp-vs.aspx) available.